# Суммирование столбца таблицы MySQL в зависимости от значения строки

Tags: php, mysql

Допустим есть таблица workers в mySQL. В таблице есть поля id, name, department, salary. Поле department содержит название отдела где работает сотрудник. Это может быть отдел продаж , логистика, бухгалтерия и т д. А поле salary содержит зарплату сотрудника. Хотелось бы узнать например общую заработную плату например сотрудников отдела логистики. Как можно (или можно ли вообще сделать так) суммировать значения поля salary выборочно. Т е в моём случае из поля salary суммировать только те строки где в поле department встречается слово "логистика". И вывести в PHP )

```
SELECT  SUM(salary) FROM workers;
```

Выводит зарплату всех сотрудников независимо от отдела.

Comment: `... WHERE department = ID_ОТДЕЛА` ?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ,  br3t . Значит Запрос и вывод на экран через PHP должно выглядит так <?php 
  $query=mysqli_query( "SELECT SUM(salary) FROM workers WHERE department = ID_ОТДЕЛА"); 
  $sum=mysqli_result($query,0); 
  echo $sum; 
?>

Comment: `"SELECT SUM(salary) FROM workers WHERE department = 'логистика' "`

Comment: Спасибо , понял. Попробую ну там слово логистика может меняться в завистимости от того что выбрал пользователь. По этому и написал ID_ОТДЕЛА. Благодарю за помощь

Comment: Можно также использовать `GROUP BY`, чтобы посмотреть зарплаты по отделам

Comment: А вот это уже интересно. Дело в том что у меня там 27 полей (( и каждую из них суммировать таким образом тоже не дело. А как можно сделать через group_by подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: `SELECT SUM(salary), department FROM workers GROUP BY department;`

Comment: ) Спасибо. Надо было в ответ поставить я бы принял)

Comment: И для `department` лучше использовать числовые идентификаторы, привязывая их названия через собственную таблицу отделов.

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Так и сделаю